# pscp connection time out

Tags: ubuntu, putty, scp, timeout

Trying to copy from Ubuntu Server to my Windows 7 machine. SSH'd into the server using Putty, navigated to the directory containing my file and ran the command:

```
pscp -P 2222 FileToCopy.txt User@WindowsIP:C:\path\to\save
```

After a minute or so I receive the error Fatal: Connection Timed Out

Is something wrong with my command syntax or is there a setting within Putty or my server I need to edit to maintain the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, Windows doesn't start an SSH server by default, so you have to initiate the connection from the Windows machine. Try running from a shell on the Windows box:

```
pscp user@bunutu:/path/to/file .
```

Comment: I can make the connection using the putty client on my windows machine and navigate the server, edit files etc the only problem comes when copying files across the two. Nevertheless I did try this from a windows shell and got "pscp is not recognised as an internal or external command..."

Comment: Everything you mentioned is working only on the server - i.e. you're doing what PuTTY was designed to allow you to do. Copying is different. You just need to download the pscp binary from the PuTTY download page. Like PuTTY, it's not a part of stock Windows.

Comment: Ok I think I see what you mean. I've downloaded and installed the PSCP binary into my home directory on windows and can bring it up by typing pscp in a shell as you suggested. If I understand correctly I have to use the windows shell pscp to copy files and not the shell window brought up by putty when opening my ssh connection?

EDIT: Problem solved I've successfully transferred my first file, thanks